# How to group by same data with connected records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table output like....

```
srno billno particular Qty rate vat amount paid balance
 1     25     aaa       5   20   5    105   400   135
 2     25     qqq       5   50   5    225   400   135
 3     25     fff       10  20   5    205   400   135
 4     26     aaa       10  20   5    205   300   245
 5     26     fff       10  20   5    205   300   245
```

but I want output like:

```
srno billno particular Qty rate vat amount paid balance
 1     25     aaa       5   20   5    105   400   135
              qqq       5   50   5    225         
              fff       10  20   5    205         
 2     26     aaa       10  20   5    205   300   245
              fff       10  20   5    205
```

How to get this output with a T-SQL select command....

Comment: That's a **display** problem - handle it on your frontend UI or your report layer - this is *not* a database issue...

Comment: I agree with @marc_s, this looks like something best done on a front-end output by grouping (using the grouping headers in Crystal reports for example). The first example is what I'd expect to get out of the database.

Comment: but i am not using crystal report. i want to show it on grid view....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using the [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) functions [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`dense_rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select 
  case when rn = 1 then cast(rnk as varchar(10)) else '' end srno,
  case when rn = 1 then cast(billno as varchar(10)) else '' end billno,
  [particular], 
  [Qty], 
  [rate], 
  [vat], 
  [amount], 
  case when rn = 1 then cast([paid] as varchar(10)) else '' end [paid], 
  case when rn = 1 then cast([balance] as varchar(10)) else '' end [balance]
from
(
  select [srno], [billno], [particular], [Qty], [rate], [vat], [amount], [paid], [balance],
    row_number() over(partition by billno order by srno) rn,
    dense_rank() over(order by billno) rnk
  from yourtable
) src;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce74b/18)

The result is:

```
| SRNO | BILLNO | PARTICULAR | QTY | RATE | VAT | AMOUNT | PAID | BALANCE |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |     25 |        aaa |   5 |   20 |   5 |    105 |  400 |     135 |
|      |        |        qqq |   5 |   50 |   5 |    225 |      |         |
|      |        |        fff |  10 |   20 |   5 |    205 |      |         |
|    2 |     26 |        aaa |  10 |   20 |   5 |    205 |  300 |     245 |
|      |        |        fff |  10 |   20 |   5 |    205 |      |         |
```